# IntelliJ + Scala deadlock

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I got this problem on all latests IDEA releases (15.0.5, 16.1.1) on my Linux Mint:

when IDE starts to import my sbt project, it takes 100% CPU and don't response any more.

Are there any known bugs with this?

==== UPDATED =====

Fixed somehow by importing project without JDK first.

As mentioned in comments, looks like it's related with https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10105

Comment: As for your last question, how about googling? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files . I don't know what could cause your problem, but it might be just downloading dependencies or indexing, although it should stay responsive.

Comment: intellij is awesome, but really resource-consumer. In big projects I need to wait some time when indexing/updating sbt dependencies, but it's not often

Comment: Similar bug was fixed yesterday:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10105
Fix is already available in [nightly](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+Nightly) and [eap](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+EAP+15) builds.

Comment: @niktrop thanks for the link, it's really very similar to my problem